# Active Directory : Get all "Security Group"

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, active-directory

I'd like to get all groups "Security Groups" available in the Active Diectory.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Since you're on .NET 3.5 or higher, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
// with the security group flag set
GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
qbeGroup.IsSecurityGroup = true;

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

Comment: when I do found.GetGroups() exception "the server is not operational" but before I get groups associated with a user. In fact I'd like get all. My explanation is not good, I'd like the groups of the OU (Organisation Unit) "Security Groups"

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
           DirectoryEntry ent1 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + _path, 
           "adminUser", "***********");

            DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(ent1);

            dSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group))";

            dSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

            SearchResultCollection results = dSearch.FindAll();
            List<string> groupNames = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
            {
                DirectoryEntry de = results[i].GetDirectoryEntry();

                groupNames.Add(de.Name.Replace("CN=", ""));


            }
```

It's working for me :)